# oauthService.getIdentityClaims() returns null when using angular-oauth2-oidc and keycloak

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, keycloak, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm working on angular-oauth2-oidc and keycloak. I can login (redirecting to keycloak login page), and session has created inside keycloak for loggedin user.

However, oauthService.getIdentityClaims() returns null so I can't get the username from this:

Below is my code:

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  envName: 'local',
  keycloak:{
    issuer:"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MySSOApp",
    redirectUri:"http://localhost:4202/",
    clientId:"sso-app3-client",
    scope:"openid profile email"
  }
};
```

sso-config.ts

```
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export const authCodeFlowConfig: AuthConfig = {
    // Url of the Identity Provider
    issuer: environment.keycloak.issuer,

    redirectUri: environment.keycloak.redirectUri,

    clientId: environment.keycloak.clientId,

    // dummyClientSecret: 'secret',

    responseType: 'code',

    scope: environment.keycloak.scope,

    requireHttps: false,    

    showDebugInformation: true,

    disableAtHashCheck: true,

    strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false
};

export class OAuthModuleConfig {
    resourceServer: OAuthResourceServerConfig = {sendAccessToken: false};
}

export class OAuthResourceServerConfig {
   
    allowedUrls?: Array<string>;
    sendAccessToken = true;
    customUrlValidation?: (url: string) => boolean;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService, NullValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { authCodeFlowConfig } from 'src/app/sso-config';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'sso-app';

  name: string = "";
  private _decodedAccessToken: any;
  private _decodedIDToken: any;
  get decodedAccessToken() { return this._decodedAccessToken; }
  get decodedIDToken() { return this._decodedIDToken; }

  @ViewChild('yourChild' /* #name or Type*/, {static: false}) child: any;

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.initAuth();
  }

  async initAuth(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolveFn, rejectFn) => {
      // setup oauthService
      this.oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
      this.oauthService.setStorage(localStorage);
      this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new NullValidationHandler();

      // subscribe to token events
      this.oauthService.events.pipe(filter((e: any) => {
        console.log("e : ", e);
        return e.type === 'token_received';
      })).subscribe(() => {
        console.log("here..");
        this.handleNewToken();
      });

      this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin().then(isLoggedIn => {
        console.log("isLoggedIn: ", isLoggedIn);
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
          resolveFn();
        } else {          
          this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
          rejectFn();
        }
      });

    });
  }

  private handleNewToken() {
    this._decodedAccessToken = this.oauthService.getAccessToken();
    this._decodedIDToken = this.oauthService.getIdToken();
  }

}
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string = "";

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) { }

  @Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  givenName:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const userClaims: any = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
    console.log(userClaims);
    if(userClaims){
      this.givenName = userClaims.name ? userClaims.name : "";
    }    
  }

  login() {    
      this.someEvent.next('somePhone');
  }

  logout() {
    this.oauthService.logOut();
  }

  // get givenName() {
  //   const claims: any = this.oauthService.getIdentityClaims();
  //   console.log("Claims ======>>>>>>", claims);
  //   if (!claims) {
  //     return null;
  //   }
  //   return claims['name'];
  // }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './components/welcome/welcome.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthConfig, OAuthModule, OAuthService, OAuthStorage } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { authCodeFlowConfig, OAuthModuleConfig } from './sso-config';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }, // anything that didn't match above routes then redirect to products
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }, // anything that didn't match above routes then redirect to products
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    var hasIdToken = this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken();
    var hasAccessToken = this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken();

    console.log("==", hasIdToken);
    console.log("==", hasAccessToken);

    if ((hasAccessToken)) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(["/welcome"]);
    return false;
  }

}
```

Any idea what I needs to be done here to work it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Did you found any solution? I came across the exact same problem. and would be thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with your routes. Please try to change

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

to

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

without the slash.

Check [this issue](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/76#issuecomment-332933079) for additional info.

Comment: I tried that but its not working

Comment: @J.K.A. did you resolve this issue?